# Repeater displaying only first record with CSS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer

In the below code by using DIV tag repeater is displaying only first one record retrieved from database. By removing DIV tag `mbody` everything is working fine. But to align the format of the script I started to use this DIV tag but I am unable to view add records. Please check where the error is at.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="Timer1" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Shout_Box" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate><div id="mbody">
           <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Message") %>
        </div> </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater><div id="sbox_button">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" /></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate><div id="sb_text"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" Width="400" Height="60" /></div></ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the above code 1 repeater, 1 button and 1 textbox are used. By adding text to the textbox and clicking button the textbox's value goes to database and retrieved by using timer. This script is a kind of chat script. But using DIV tag I am unable to display all records :-(

**Server side code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=chatserver;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=*****;" + "OPTION=3";
        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        try
        {
            MyConnection.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select message from shoutbox", MyConnection);
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                    string ep = dr[0].ToString();
                    values.Add(new PositionData(ep));
                    Shout_Box.DataSource = values;
                    Shout_Box.DataBind();
            }
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=chatserver;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=*****;" + "OPTION=3";
            OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO shoutbox(name, message)VALUES(?, ?)", MyConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = "tick";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OdbcType.Text).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            MyConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
            TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            UpdatePanel2.Update();
    }
```

Comment: Show us the whole code, that's no good.

Comment: I believe this must be CSS error.

Comment: Just a thought, but are there more than 1 row in the database table? If it is a shoutbox, are you sure that the input of the shouts is working?

Answer (score 0):

Move the databinding out of the while loop:

```
        while (dr.Read())
        {
                string ep = dr[0].ToString();
                values.Add(new PositionData(ep));
        }
        Shout_Box.DataSource = values;
        Shout_Box.DataBind();
```

It does not make any sense to bind the data after reading every value.